# Redirect subomain access to HTTPS but not Custom domain access

Tags: redirect, nginx, https

I am having a bit of trouble with NGINX, I have a goal to make NGINX behave such that it will redirect all subdomain access to https:

```
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.myappdomain123.com;

    #Redirect all nonssl requests to ssl.
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
```

This works, however, the problem is even the request to domains that points to a subdomain is redirected. Example: `www.myhostedwebsite.com` points to (via CNAME) `myhostedwebsite.myappdomain123.com`, now even this `www.myhostedwebsite.com` domain is redirected to HTTPS which should not happen. What could be wrong here?

Comment: Where do you want `www.myhostedwebsite.com` to redirect to?

Comment: Redirect to use https

Comment: You question states that it *is* redirected to https - so what exactly are you asking?

Comment: Redirect subdomain access (e.g. `http://myhostedwebsite.myappdomain123.com` to `https://myhostedwebsite.myappdomain123.com`) but not www.myhostedwebsite.com which points to the same subdomain